# How does the new Challenge mode work?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have two questions here, but both deal with the new "challenge mode" in Warcraft.

1) How does one go about running an instance in challenge mode? In other words, is there something specific that you have to do before starting the instance in order to put it into challenge mode, or is it something that can be done inside of the dungeon once it's already started?

2) I noticed that there is a daily quest at the bottom of the Shrine of Two Moons (this is the Horde city, but I'm sure there's one at the Alliance also) and it appears to be a random daily for doing an instance in challenge mode. Am I correct on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run an instance in challenge mode, you must form your party and manually enter the instance after setting the dungeon difficulty to challenge mode. This also adds certain user interface elements to the game in place of the usual quest tracker, showing you how much time you've taken in the challenge mode so far, and providing you the option to reset the challenge mode to have another go at it.

[Quoted from the Battle.net website](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/game/mists-of-pandaria/feature/challenge-modes):

> You select Challenge Mode before you enter a dungeon. In this mode, your objective is to clear the instance and down all the dungeon's bosses as fast as you can.

It is possible to see your best challenge mode times through the 'Challenges' interface, accessible by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> and selecting the 'Challenges' tab:

[image: challenge mode finder]

The quest at the new faction cities for both Horde and Alliance is for completing a challenge mode, this changes daily and there is one quest for each of the new instances.

More information about challenge modes can be [found on the official Battle.net website](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/game/mists-of-pandaria/feature/challenge-modes)

Comment: Ah... I'd wondered if you manually had to setup a group. So there's no way that a random pug can do an instance in challenge mode. So are the bosses in challenge mode any harder than they are in heroic mode?

Comment: Yeah they hit harder but it's manageable in the gear you're scaled to, it requires more communication in order for you to get through in a reasonable time though.

Comment: In all honesty, I would have to say Challenge Mode dungeons are harder than LFR. All of your gear gets scaled down to 463 ilvl(this includes the majority of the stats on the gear except gems and enchants) and anything below 463 ilvl remains the same. So along with the fact that the mobs now hit even harder than they did on Heroic, you have to deal with having less health, doing less damage, getting fewer heals, so on and so forth.

Comment: Hardly - at the point in time that challenge mode dungeons were introduced item level 463 was 'pretty high up' in the scale of things. Sure things hit harder, but ultimately it's about coordination and speed more than being able to faceroll your way through the instances.